# ARM Assembly - Use of curly braces

Tags: assembly, arm

I have found instructions like this in my ARMv5 assembly:

```
pop     {r2} ; (str r2, [sp, #-4]!)
push    {r0} ; (str r0, [sp, #-4]!)
push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, lr}
```

I understand that push and pop are acronyms for `STR` and `LDR` and that these instructions store and load to multiple registers therefore I believe that that curly braces in this case means a *"set for registers being stored or loaded"*

**Is my assumption correct?**

Comment: Sounds like it.

Comment: Don't assume, read the reference manuals.

Comment: An don't use S.O. either?

Comment: Right, don't use SO either, for stuff that "does not show research effort" because you will be downvoted.

Comment: How do you believe I arrive to this 'assumption' without research effort?

Comment: By "imagination" ... you said. Research would have been reading the manual which says _"reglist is a list of one or more registers to be loaded, enclosed in braces. It can contain register ranges. It must be comma separated if it contains more than one register or register range."_

Comment: Thanks. I will delete the question. However, given enough research effort, any question can be solved without asking here, therefore by 'reductio ad absurdum' let me ask you, is S.O. is useless? . Another way of seeing S.O. is that it is a highly visible source of information for others and that your 'lack of research effort' can be useful to others in the form of Q&A.

Comment: push a set of registers would be STMDB SP!,{...}(store multiple decrement sp before), pop a set of registers would be LDMIA SP!,{...} (load multiple increment sp after).

Comment: @Jester - it's possible that El Marce's manual didn't make it clear that push and pop translate into STMDB SP!,{...} and LDMIA SP!,{...}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, just read the instruction set documentation.  The assembler could choose to use str/ldr or stm/ldm for those single register pushes and pops.  These days you want to keep the stack aligned on a 64 bit boundary so generally an even number of registers is pushed or popped, but you can do one at a time if you have to.  For thumb push/pop are their own instructions not encodings of load or store.

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e49d2004    pop {r2}        ; (ldr r2, [sp], #4)
   4:   e52d0004    push    {r0}        ; (str r0, [sp, #-4]!)
   8:   e92d40f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   bc04        pop {r2}
   2:   b401        push    {r0}
   4:   b5f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
```

In this case the ARM encodings do appear to be load/store not just the disassembler comment (x4xxxxxx) ldm/stm is a x8xxxxxx encoding like the last one.

All of this is of course in these ARM documents that answer this and possibly other questions you may have.  Sure stackoverflow can be though of useless if every answer can be figured out.  But in this case you are examining some reference that shows the syntax, that same reference should have some additional text showing that the register list is a set.  There are 15 or 9 bits respectively in the encoding, and with a few simple examples you can see the encoding matches the list you specify in the syntax.

Yes the curly braces mean push all of them or pop all of them as the case may be.  The documentation also covers the decrement before increment after settings as well as what registers are put in memory in what order, is

```
push {r2,r3,r4}
```

different from

```
push {r4,r2,r3}
```

for example

Also note originally there were no push/pop instructions, they came along with the real push/pop thumb instructions which are not ldm/stm (because they dont have enough bits to burn for r13 being specified four bits out of 16, the ldm/stm they have is limited to r0-r7).  Likewise you had to specify all three registers for three register operations, then later the assembler(s) let you be lazy let you use thumb syntax for arm instructions, and then eventually the unified syntax, which just makes things more complicated not less.

Most importantly remember that assembly languages in general are not standardized.  They are only defined by the specific assembler you are using the program that reads the text, someone could easily allow this

```
push (r1,r2)
pop [r3,r4]
push r2,r3,r4,r5
str r3,r2
```

as legal syntax in their assembler.  Just look at the differences between the arm tools and the gnu tools for the same instruction sets.  Even more fun look at the pdp-11 gnu assembler syntax compared to the traditional pdp-11 syntax. (yes there is a maintained pdp-11 backend).

So your question should have been more specific as to what assembler you were using, even though we pretty much knew what you were asking.

Comment: when I asked the question I was expecting a simple "yes or no" kind of answer. But your went beyond that and I learned a lot today, I did not know about assembler languages not being standard. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the problem that I have with this answer: it's condescending. It's a long and good answer. However, it would have been a much nicer read if all the "look into the documentation" stuff was left out. It would have been a short and better good answer. The ARM documentation is huge and can be intimidating for beginners that just need a quick answer, which I think was the case.

Comment: @SenhorLucas This, and also beginners often do not know what to look for or have the key context to understand what they're looking at. Sometimes you need different explanations to get enough of a conceptual understanding to make sense of documentation. Otherwise this is a good answer.